# Whenever I attempt to download a file on Windows 10, I get a network error, unless I'm in safe mode or using Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-10, networking, download, safe-mode

I have tried disabling non-Microsoft Services in system configuration. I have also tried disabling start-up programs in task manager. Furthermore, I have tried running my browsers as admin. I have tried all of the aforementioned and to no avail. I am able to download programs using Internet Explorer - usually after the download fails on the first attempt, when I resume.
I have also run Malwarebytes and CCcleaner. I have even tried reinstalling Windows. Nothing works! Please assist.

For some reason, I have no trouble downloading anything in Safe Mode, regardless of the browser. I just can't figure out what drivers or apps are causing this problem.

In addition, I tried running the following commands in the Command Prompt:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew 
ipconfig /registerdns 
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh advfirewall reset
ipconfig /flushdns
route /f
```

[Failed download on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbf5h.png)

[Failed download on Brave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2ojg.png)

Comment: can you download anything else from the net? e.g. the chrome installer? as you showed us the error for the same file and on the firefox window it clearly says that the source is not found, so it seems there might be an issue on the server side.

Comment: Yes, for some reason I was able to download Chrome. Weird.

Comment: ... But it won't download larger files. I tried downloading GlassWire, for instance, and it won't work on any of the faster, more secure browsers. I was able to download that program using Internet Explorer - but, even then, the download kept failing and I Had to resume several times.

Answer (score 0):

> I have even tried reinstalling Windows.

Try first:

Update BIOS, Chipset (if one) and the Network Card Drivers. Restart after this.

Try second:  A USB Network Adapter. Your hardware could have a fault.

Comment: I'm already using a USB network adapter. I use the same adapter on both of my machines and it works fine - been using it for well over a year. I'm going to try updating the BIOS. Thanks for your input! I'll post the results.

Comment: Perhaps a long shot but perhaps try a different adapter for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I switched the adapter out with the same make and model on my Linux machine. On that machine, both adapters will work and both have worked on Windows ... I can surf the web just fine. In fact, I'm on the Windows 10 with troublesome downloads machine now. Like I said, everything does work in Safe Mode, which confounds the issue even further. I don't think it's the adapter. I didn't find a chipset (I assume it doesn't have one), and the BIOS is up-to-date according to my HP assistant program.

Comment: You might try reinstalling Windows again. I cannot see from the above why your networking does not work in regular mode.

Comment: I've already tried reinstalling Windows three times. This is some weird stuff going on. It must be caused by some program or driver in the background - given it works in Safe Mode - but I don't know which one. If you have any more ideas, John, please let me know.

Comment: Try the following: Start in Safe Mode and list all the Services running (Admin tools, Services).  Then start in Safe mode and see what additional Services are running. Does something stand out.  Do the same thing with Task Manager programs and processes before and after (= regular mode)

Comment: You mean, first start in regular mode... I think you may have made a typo.

Comment: You can start either way, record results, start in the other mode, do the same tests and record differences

Comment: I went back to my first comment and yes there was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were right to think there's a program interfering. This make sense since it works under safe mode. It could be another program that identifies itself as system level so don't just think 3rd party program.

I had a similar issue previously where a 'proxy' was trying to intercept all my data. Yes a virus. But since you reinstalled, it sounds like there's a network configuration problem somewhere. Since your other machines are working, we can rule out the modem/router. Since there's rarely configuration issues with Ethernet lines, I'm guessing  you're on wifi, which some wifi adapters are a little more finicky than others. Go through your wifi adapter settings.  (right click start, device manager, network adapters, right click yours, then properties, then advanced. Try different settings in the advanced heading, and look for something weird. If you really want to learn, you can google the settings to see what they are and what they should be). Turn off power save and turn on gaming in the advanced settings.

Also if you have any networking software, like access point software or something, disable it. Obviously your network is working until the browser tries to download something big. Could be a QoS scheduler or something similar.

Again, besides v6 issues, it could be your windows wifi driver isn't keeping up with Windows updates. Would have to check the wifi chipset to see if it's still supported, or find a newer driver for the chipset if your manufacturer isn't releasing new drivers.

When you do a fresh install of Windows, make sure to test it before installing other software that might modify settings, like vmware, virtual box, or supplied wifi connection software like use to be needed 20 years ago.

Comment: Working on this with Jeremiah Calvin. We're going to troubleshoot everything with Wireshark, then keep everyone posted on the results. I can download some stuff e.g., I successfully downloaded the Wireshark binary ... But lots of other programs, especially those high in data, invariably fail. It'll be interesting to see where this leads.

Comment: I have one theory though it's a longshot. I use the same USB network adapter on another computer which sits adjacent to the problem child. What if ... and this is a big if ... the network adapters are interfering with each other and I'm getting some cross-talk. That's probably not what's up but it's a possibility! That seems less likely though as the other computer doesn't have nearly the same download issues - however, they're running different OSes ...